# PostgreSQL repmgr Standby Server fail to Start

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

In repmgr, I had register the master server, but at the Standby server, i had cloned the Master backup to Standby data directory sucessfully. But after cloning while starting the Standby server, I got the following error.

```
    Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in -d at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 354.
Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 355.
Error:  is not accessible or does not exist
```

Please help in this issue.

Comment: What repmgr version are you using? On what operating system and version?

Comment: I am using the version repmgr 2.0beta1 (PostgreSQL 9.3.2) for both Server & Standby. Os - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I cloned to the different Directory not the Existing data Directory. Is that is the Problem...?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I able to solve it. I had to clone the Master backup to the Data directory of the (Default) Standby data Directory (`/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`).

If we need to keep the data directory separate (Apart from Default), It raises the error. If anyone solved by configuring the data directory separately,  please help me.

Comment: The location of the data directory is specified in `postgresql.conf`

Comment: Yes Specified in there. But When Changing 'data_directory' to the other path raise the Error. It only accept the Default one.

Comment: Please help me to solve that, I need the Cluster location to be different data directory not the default one.

Comment: The "cluster location to be different data directory" doesn't make sense. The "cluster" and the "data directory" are the same thing.